# cannot load such file -- capybara (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm trying to run a ruby file that uses capybara and selenium.

When I run `cucumber`, I get the error :

```
cannot load such file -- capybara (LoadError)
```

I saw in another answer that, in order to solve this problem, I had to install poltergeist, but when I run - `gem install poltergeist`
, I get the error `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to include/install the `capybara` gem, not poltergeist.

Comment: I get exactly the same error when running this command **ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running `cucumber` with params `-v -b` , so that you can see where it's failed with verbose & backtrace log.

```
cucumber -v -b <your_cucumber_features/tag>
```

The message

```
cannot load such file -- capybara (LoadError)
```

was prompted when you've defined to use `capybara` in your ruby file but your machine hasn't been installed that gem. So need installing capybara via

```
gem install capybara
```

However, gem will be installed to specific RVM, so that if you have any error, then try to see which Ruby version that you install onto your system. I suggest install **rbenv** so that you can manage it better.